# Print float as decimal and fix wrong output

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with classes and I wrote this example code. The user enters their register number and two marks. The output should be their register number and the average of the two input marks. I have two questions:

1. How do I use the `float` type to display the output average marks in decimal form if I am using constructors?
2. Why is the output of the register number not correct? The code is given below.

   ```
   #include<iostream.h>
   #include<conio.h>

   class abc
   {
       int reg, mark1, mark2;

       public:
       int avg;
       abc(int reg, int mark1, int mark2)
       {
           avg = (mark1 + mark2) / 2;
       }

       void display()
       {
           cout<<"Your average mark is:\n"<<avg<<"\n";
           cout<<"Your Register Number is:\n"<<reg<<"\n";
       }
   };

   void main()
   {
       clrscr();

       int num, m1, m2;

       cout << "Enter your register number\n";
       cin >> num;

       cout << "Enter your Mark 1 and Mark 2:\n";
       cin >> m1 >> m2;

       abc s1(num,m1,m2);
       s1.display();

       getch();
   }
   ```

I am getting the average (**without** the decimal) and the register number output is `11196`.

Comment: `reg` is ambiguous, as both constructor parameter and class property. You have to fix that. You have to save the value of `reg` passed as parameter to the class member `reg`, and therefore `reg` used in `display()` is unitialized. I'm pretty sure the compiler fired some warnings about that, you should read those warnings.

Comment: Edited my answer, it should solve your problem now.

Comment: *"Where did I go wrong?"* - You use non-standard, ancient, proprietary C-style C++. Get rid of `<conio.h>` and all functions it provides, replace `<iostream.h>` with `<iostream>`, make `main` return `int`, use initialisation and not assignment in the constructor. You should also use a modern compiler. I have the feeling that you are still using VC6.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the constructor arguments are not automatically stored in the class members.  I would change your class declaration to the following, note that I have used different names for the members and function arguments (I like to use `m_` for private member variables).

```
class abc
{
  int m_reg, m_mark1, m_mark2;
public:
  int avg;

  abc (int reg, int mark1, int mark2)
    : m_reg(reg), m_mark1(mark1), m_mark2(mark2)
  {
    avg = (m_mark1+m_mark2)/2;
  }

  void display()
  {
    cout<<"Your average mark is:\n"<<avg<<"\n";
    cout<<"Your Register Number is:\n"<<m_reg<<"\n";
  }
};
```

If you expect your result to be a decimal (and not rounded or floored to the nearest integer) you need to change your average declaration and calculation to:

```
// The new declaration
double avg;

// In your constructor
avg = (double) (m_mark1 + m_mark2) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add value to **reg** property in your class constructor:

```
abc (int r, int mark1, int mark2)
{
    reg = r;
    avg = (mark1+mark2)/2;
}
```

In addition to that, why is avg an integer instead of double? Consider this:

```
class abc
{
    int reg,mark1,mark2;
    public:
    double avg;

    abc (int r, int mark1, int mark2)
    {
        reg = r;
        avg = (double)(mark1+mark2)/2.00;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Your average mark is:\n"<<(int)avg<<"\n";
        cout<<"Your Register Number is:\n"<<reg<<"\n";
    }
};
```

If you want 4.4 to be displayed as 4, and 4.5 as 5 use this hack:

```
avg = avg + 0.5;
cout << (int)avg << "\n";
```